# How can I improve my question about FPGA programming?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, vote-to-close, downvote-reason

Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60957971/understanding-the-sb-io-primitive-in-lattice-ice40

Apparently, I have made the false assumption that providing feedback is mandatory on down/close votes. [No, it is not.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Let's talk about this particular question: what makes it so bad that it deserves 0 upvotes, 8 downvotes, 3 close votes, and 2 delete votes? I understand that I shouldn't have made the edit asking for an explanation for the down/close votes, but that edit has already been rolled back.

Comment: An extended (and obsolete) discussion about explaining close/downvotes was [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210780/discussion-on-question-by-nalzok-how-can-i-improve-this-question-with-unexplain).

Comment: I'm also going to go against the grain here and say that I think your question on the main site is fine. I do not believe it is too broad to be reasonably answered. The questions you ask, while there is technically more than one, all fall under a single umbrella and are a valid fit for our Q&A format. As such, I've re-opened the question.

Answer (score 12):

You're asking for a detailed explanation of something, and you're asking multiple other questions. This falls under "Needs more focus":

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Additionally, users cannot tell why you are failing to grasp something or why something is too complex for you to interpret. If you had a *single* question about a *specific* part of this, it may be answerable *if* you provide details about why you don't understand it.

> This is how you treat a clueless beginner?

I hardly consider you a clueless beginner. You have 10,497 reputation, and 213 other questions. By now, you should've learned how to write a good question.

> but those who think it is a good idea to downvote or close vote without telling me how to make an improvement have really really pissed me off. Stack Overflow wasn't so disappointing in the past when people will at least tell you what is wrong with your post.

Sorry, but this is the way things are now. I (and everybody else here) have to deal with a *lot* of bad questions by people who just want to get an answer. Now I don't know if those people want to improve their questions or if they will just yell at me for giving them some constructive criticism.

Comment: I meant to say I am a clueless beginner in FPGA. As you have noticed, I have asked quite a lot question in the past that were upvoted, and this is the first time I got down/close voted without a comment, which makes me extremely confused and unhappy. Thanks for your explanation, and that makes sense to me, but at this point I probably shouldn’t bother to edit such a heavily downvoted and closed question. (Maybe deleting it and asking a new one with more focus would work?) If only your comment comes earlier on the main site. But still, better late than never, so thanks again!

Comment: @nalzok "_If only your comment comes earlier on the main site_" - My experience from commenting like that: users don't want to listen and begin to argue. It just doesn't scale. I grew weary of repeating the same things again and again, dealing with getting yelled at or being ignored. If users would be more prepared to listen to advice things would be different.